# why swapping value using pointer doesn't work?

Tags: c++, c, function, pointers

I have written the following code. It should swap the values of two variables ... but, as soon as I compile the code it shows swap.exe has stopped working...
Why doesn't it work?

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void swap(int *x, int *y)
{
    int *temp;
    *temp=*x;
    *x=*y;
    *y=*temp;
}
int main()
{
    int i=5,j=10;
    swap(&i,&j);
    cout<<i<<" "<<j<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

How to fix this problem?
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: what does `int *temp;` point to ? (it's not question, it's answer)

Comment: So... you `using namespace std;` and then go ahead and define a function that has the same name as something in the `std` namespace? Please don't. Either get rid of the `using` or rename swap.

Comment: Does it even compile? I mean `int *temp;` shouldn't be dereferrenced (`*temp = *x;`) doesn't look valid to me

Comment: You should enable warnings (`-Wall -Wextra` for *gcc*/*clang*) and fix them. If you had that, you would have gotten warning about using `temp` uninitialized.

Comment: I don't quite get the voting patterns of some people, downvoting a novice question, upvoting answers (especially answers which don't answer the more important "what's wrong with my code" question) to it... But maybe question and answer voters are different people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to

```
void swap(int *x, int *y)
{
    int temp;
    temp=*x;
    *x=*y;
    *y=temp;
}
```

If you want to swap two `int`s why do you use a pointer to `int` as temporary variable? Use the same type.

Answer (score 3):

Because `temp` is a dangling pointer, so accessing `*temp` is undefined behavior.

You can use `int temp;` and `temp = *x; ...`, or just use `std::swap`.

Answer (score 3):

It does not work, because you copy the content of `x` to a location that is pointed by an uninitialized pointer (`temp`).

If you simply want to swap the contents of `x` and `y` you may use `std::swap(*x, *y)`.

Answer (score 2):

use temp as int not as int * as in:

```
void swap(int *x, int *y)
{
    int temp;
    temp=*x;
    *x=*y;
    *y=temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

declare `int temp` as just a int type variable, not a pointer. Because you are just storing value of x in temp, not pointing to x.